# Inheritance between 3 classes in python

Tags: python

I'm creating with PyQt5 a program that creates wordclouds.

The program has:
1.  a main window that gets the text and generate a wordcloud
2.  a settings window that has 3 color options

I need to pass the user chosen color from the settings window to the main window.
For that, i've created 3 classes:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, colormap):
           self.colormap = colormap

    def set_colormap(self, x):
           self.colormap = x

    def get_colormap(self):
           return self.colormap

#in the real program this class represents the second window with the color pick options:#
class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self, "blue")
           self.c = A("blue")

    def userColorChoice(self):
           userinput = input("Choose ColorMap: \n")
#in the real program there are 3 button for options instead of this input#
           c.set_colormap(userinput)
```

And:

```
from test2 import B

#in the real program this represnts the class of the main window which includes the create wordcloud function:#
class C(B):

    def __init__(self):
            Func = B()
            self.ChosenColorMap = Func.c.get_colormap()

    def create_wordcloud(self):
            #here i'm using the self.ChosenColorMap#
```

My problem is that when i use the `self.ChosenColorMap` in my `class C` it gets the default value of `self.c` (in this case: "blue") and not the user choice.

I think that the problem is in `Func = B()` in `class C` because whenever i call it, it initialize `self.c` to "blue".

How can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you call the function that asks the user for their color choice? Would you not just want to call `self.userColorChoice()` and then look at `self.get_colormap()`?

Comment: `self.userColorChoice()` is connected to a button. Whenever the user clicks on the button, the color choice changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have a couple of issues in your code. Let's start with your `C` class. Here you create an object of class B named Func, and ask for its color map. The reference in Func isn't stored anywhere. So as soon as your `__init__(self)` method in your `C` class completes, the reference in Func is lost. You should initiate your C class similarly to how you initiate your B class, by actually initiating the parent, class A. Your assignment of self.c is still most likely not what you want.

Let's look at your class B. You initiate the parent, then assign `self.c` a new instance of A. This means that `self.c` doesn't reference the same A object that you inherit from.

Based on this I'd say you need to look over how to initiate your object hierarchies properly to fix this. For Python 3 you can take a look at https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php to start with. How to do this changed when Python 3 saw the light of day. Python 2 does it differently, see https://www.python-course.eu/inheritance_example.php for Python 2. There are of course other sites describing this to a varying degree.

Comment: If you use `class A(object):` you can use the Python 3 thing iirc.